# Check if elements of one array are present in an other array - within a certain index

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 2 arrays:

```
arr1 = ['banana', 'apple', 'orange', 'tomato', 'grape']
arr2 = ['banana', 'grape']
```

I'm trying to check:

- if elements of arr2 are present in arr1
- BUT only between index 0 and 2 in arr1

I'm trying the following code:

```
if (arr2.some(fruit => arr1.indexOf(fruit) >= 0) && arr2.some(fruit => arr1.indexOf(fruit) <= 2)) {
 //do something }
```

The above code with the above named arr1 and arr2 should return TRUE. With the following alternative array2 the code should return FALSE:

```
arr2 = ['tomato', 'grape'] //false
```

I think there is something wrong with how I'm adressing the range of possible indexes. I tried several alternatives, but nothing worked. Does anyone have an idea what I could try? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for both the conditions inside the `some` method.

The code below will only check if any element in `arr2` falls in that range, if you want all elements to be within that range use `every` instead of `some`.

```js
const arr1 = ["banana", "apple", "orange", "tomato", "grape"];
const arr2 = ["banana", "grape"];

if (arr2.some((fruit) => arr1.indexOf(fruit) > 0 && arr1.indexOf(fruit) <= 2)) {
  console.log("Yes");
} else {
  console.log("No")
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this was the closest answer to my code and worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Your description reads as if you are tring to find out whether both elements of array 2 are within the range 0-2. In this case both items have to return true for the index check, hence the check would be an .every(). If you are really looking for a single item, use .some() instead of .every().

```
arr1 = ['banana', 'apple', 'orange', 'tomato', 'grape']
arr2 = ['banana', 'grape']

const lookUp = arr2.every(fruit =>{
    const index = arr1.indexOf(fruit);
    return index >= 0 && index <=2
})

console.log(lookUp)
//false
```

In any case, you don't need to call .some()/.every() and .indexOf() twice.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a **set** on the `arr1` **sub-array** from a `beg` to `end` index and then for each `arr2` element check if that set has them or not.

```js
const arr1 = ['banana', 'apple', 'orange', 'tomato', 'grape']
const arr2 = ['banana', 'grape']

function check(beg, end, arr1, arr2) {
  const arr1Set = new Set(arr1.slice(beg, end + 1));
  return arr2.every(ele => arr1Set.has(ele));
}

// returns false
console.log(check(0, 2, arr1, arr2));
// returns true
console.log(check(0, 4, arr1, arr2));
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try doing something like below

```js
const checkIfSetIsASubsetOfAnotherSet = (listA, listB, range) => {
    const setA = listA.slice(range.start, range.stop);
    return listB.some(listItem => setA.includes(listItem));
s};

checkIfSetIsASubsetOfAnotherSet(
    ['banana', 'apple', 'orange', 'tomato', 'grape'], 
    ['banana', 'grape'], 
    { start: 0, stop: 2 }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use filter function

```js
var arr1 = ['banana', 'apple', 'orange', 'tomato', 'grape']
var arr2 = ['banana', 'grape']

arr2 = arr1.slice(0,2).filter( ( x ) => arr2.indexOf( x ) !== -1 )

console.log(arr2 = arr2.length > 0 ? arr2 : false)
```